# target a div within multiple divs

Tags: jquery, css

The first div

[image]

The second div

[image]

So it goes like this

```
    <div class="div1">
     1st image goes here
        <div class="div2">
          the background-color goes here
          and the logo with the href
          </div>
    </div>
```

What I want to do is on mouse hover to scale the first image and change fade/opacity of the background so without effecting the logo with it staying on top.

Can I achieve this with css only or do I have to implement jQuery?

This what I have

```
    .div1{
      position: relative;
      transform:scale(1);
       transition:all 1s;
       object-fit: cover;
       display:block;
       img{
             object-fit: cover;
       }
       :hover img {
         transform:scale(1.05);
       }
      }
    }

  .div2{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:red;
  opacity:1;
  transition: opacity .35s,transform .35s;
  :hover{
   opacity:.5;
  }
 }

 .div2 img{
  width: 150px !important;
  display : block;
  margin : auto;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 40;
 }
```

when I hover the mouse the logo scales out and the div2 opacity does not reduce.

Comment: Why are you opening 2 divs and closing only one ?

Comment: Since this is a jQuery question, remove your javascript tag and add the jQuery one.

Comment: You should add the actual image tags, not just pseudocode, explain what element you want to mouse over, and what element should change, and of course what element shouldn't change etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in both ways.

If you are doing with jQuery use `onmouseover` and `mouseout`. You do not want to limited to these functions. There are many ways to achieve this using jQuery.

Else you can use CSS to achieve this.